UniswapV3 quoterV2 fees
I'm invoking quoterV2 (uniswapV3) off chain on arbitrum through python script and i wonder whether pool's fees (fraction of input tokens that goes to LPs) are taken into account in the amout-out returned from quoteExtactOutput function ?
Since QuoterV2 simulates the swap before revert it i'd say yes but i have a doubt because when i look at the transaction on arbiscan i have some discrepancies and i'm not able to say if it comes from slippage or not.
So far i did not find crystal clear answer so i'd appreciate some clarifications.
Thanks
